# React Nav Bar Click requires 2 clicks to fire active CSS using useState hook

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a useState hook that is used to update an index I then use to provide active css when a nav button is clicked. Here is a code sample:

```
const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(0);
const handleChangeActiveId = (index: number) => {
        setActiveId(index);
};


const homeClassName = `${style['nav-link']} ${style['active']} nav-item`;
const inactiveClassName = `${style['nav-link']} nav-item`;


<Link id="home" to={`/`} onClick={() => handleChangeActiveId(0)} className={(activeId === 0) ? homeClassName : inactiveClassName}><span className='item-text'></span><i className={'icon-home'} aria-hidden="true"></i><div className={style.texts}>{translatei18(`Dashboard.home`)}</div>
</Link>
{accessCard && accessCard.map((card, index) => 
(<Link key={card.id} to={`/${locale}${card.link}`} id={card.name} onClick={() => handleChangeActiveId(index + 1)} className={(activeId === (index + 1)) ? homeClassName : inactiveClassName}><i className={`${card.icon} item-text`} aria-hidden="true"></i><span className='item-text'>{translatei18(`Dashboard.cardsOptions.${card.id}.displayValue`)}{index}</span><div className={style.texts}>{translatei18(`Dashboard.cardsOptions.${card.id}.displayValue`)}</div></Link>
))}
```

The issue I'm having is that I always have to click twice in order for the css class to apply. Also, I notice that activeId doesn't get updated right away when I click. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Why not use the `NavLink` component instead? Either way, I don't see any issue here with the enqueued state update. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] and also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: You are right Drew, NavLink is the way to go here and using property activeClassName <NavLink activeClassName={activeClassName} Once I modified to NavLink, it is working properly. Thank you!

Comment: Kudos, glad to hear that it's working for you. Cheers.